# Typescript doesn't check keys in array object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array that should content an explicit object. By some reason typescript doesn't show me errors if I break this object. I use column object to knex query.

```
type Test = {
    id: string;
    startDate: string;
    percentDebitCard: number,
}

const column = {
  id: 'bct.id',
  startDate: 'bct.startDate',
  percentDebitCard: 'bct.percentDebitCard',
};

const allCashBackByType:any=[{
    id: "bla",
    startDate: "bla",
    endDate: "bla",
    someKey:"bla",
    someKey1:"bla",
    someKey2:"bla",
    someKey3:"bla"
}]

const test:Test[]=allCashBackByType.map((item: typeof column):Test => ({
    id: item.id,
    startDate: item.startDate,
    percentDebitCard: item.percentDebitCard as number,
}));
```

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

But if I remove method map that make iterations it shows errors

```
const test:Test[]=[{
    id: '11',
    startDate: "22",
    extraKey:"33"
}];
```

But I need map.

Comment: I believe it's because the `allCashBackByType` variable is of type `any` instead of `any[]`. If you change it, the error should show.

Comment: Or, remove the type annotation `any` from `const allCashBackByType: any ...`

Comment: Thanks for recommendations guys. I updated question. Take a look, please.

Comment: I even put item.percentDebitCard as number but it anyway, shows me an error.

Comment: Instead of `percentDebitCard: item.percentDebitCard as number,`, put `... percentDebitCard: +item.percentDebitCard ...`

Comment: Wow. I just forget about this trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
const test:Test[]=allCashBackByType.map((item: any): Test => ({
    id: item.id,
    startDate: item.startDate,
    extraKey: '2222'
}));
```